# Slow wordpress in eks cluster

Tags: php, wordpress, kubernetes, amazon-eks

Running wordpress in `eks` pod without volumes (all, mysql and files in pod filesystem for testing purposes) gets 1.5s average response time for `curl http://localhost`, but if I run same configuration in a `minikube` cluster it takes only 0.5s, same database and php content (restored from backup).

Where I should look to start?

I'm using this docker image https://hub.docker.com/layers/wordpress/library/wordpress/php7.4-apache/images/sha256-483ce1761cdf5580e0259f68498d6e5e331dd6038fe339c9538420a26f21275f?context=explore

Nodes have 16Gb RAM and 4 vCPU (wordpress is pink graph)
[image]

Volume instance monitoring:

[image]

Xhprof results:

[image]

Update:

I have create an isolated ec2 instance with same eks node AMI and I get the same results.

Comment: Are you curl-ing from inside the pod? Or through a proxy or something?

Comment: @MichaelJohann from inside the pod

Comment: What filters are you using in do_action? 98% of the time spent here. If you can temporary comment out this part then you can tell if this is an EKS related issue.

Comment: Of course, if I remove do_action it will spend half time, but there is no more info with this change. I'm pretty sure the problem is with ec2 (ebs).

Comment: Looking at your I/O chart posted, unlikely an EBS issue.

Comment: What kind of EC2 instance is the EKS cluster running on?

Comment: @JackBarger t3a.xlarge

Comment: T3 instances are burstable and will not give you best performance. T3a is even slower than T3. Try an M5 instance to see if you notice a big difference

Comment: Thanks @RezaNasiri, we get 25% of improvement in response time.